# Auto increment column sometimes jumps and leaves large gaps in the sequence

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `TabInvoice` with an auto-increment (1+1) column `InvoiceID`.

But there is something is wrong with (as shown in the picture).

When user enters data into `TabInvoice` (via vb.net form) till 4 records it is good but after that the column automatically changed to 1001 rather to 5 and after 1007 it changed to 2001 and so on.

Kindly guide .

[image]

I searched a lot but in vain

Comment: It's a known and well documented issue, starting with SQL Server 2012, and MS claims it was fixed in SQL Server 2019. It has to do with SQL Server caching identity values. You can influence that in various ways - but really, even those jumps shouldn't be a problem ...

Comment: You shouldn't really about the id values, they should be a primary key only. If you need a human facing key you should generate that separately.

Comment: [SQL Server’s identity column misconceptions - An Identity column generates consecutive numbers](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/10/06/sql-servers-identity-column-misconceptions/#An-Identity-column-generates-consecutive-numbers)